# Interference between a countdown directive and an angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some extremely weird interference between two angular functions in my application that I cannot explain. The end result of the problem causes this to happen:

[image]

I have a countdown directive embedded in one of my pages which is also the domain of an angular controller. Here is the countdown directive:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app');

    app.directive('countdown', ['$interval', function($interval) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                specificity: '=',
                countdownTo: '=',
                callback: '&?'
            },
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

                $scope.isLaunchExact = ($scope.specificity == 6 || $scope.specificity == 7);

                $scope.$watch('specificity', function(newValue) {
                    $scope.isLaunchExact = (newValue == 6 || newValue == 7);
                });

                var countdownProcessor = function() {

                    var launchUnixSeconds = $scope.launchUnixSeconds;
                    var currentUnixSeconds = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

                    if (launchUnixSeconds >= currentUnixSeconds) {
                        $scope.secondsAwayFromLaunch = launchUnixSeconds - currentUnixSeconds;

                        var secondsBetween = $scope.secondsAwayFromLaunch;
                        // Calculate the number of days, hours, minutes, seconds
                        $scope.days = Math.floor(secondsBetween / (60 * 60 * 24));
                        secondsBetween -= $scope.days * 60 * 60 * 24;

                        $scope.hours = Math.floor(secondsBetween / (60 * 60));
                        secondsBetween -= $scope.hours * 60 * 60;

                        $scope.minutes = Math.floor(secondsBetween / 60);
                        secondsBetween -= $scope.minutes * 60;

                        $scope.seconds = secondsBetween;

                        $scope.daysText = $scope.days == 1 ? 'Day' : 'Days';
                        $scope.hoursText = $scope.hours == 1 ? 'Hour' : 'Hours';
                        $scope.minutesText = $scope.minutes == 1 ? 'Minute' : 'Minutes';
                        $scope.secondsText = $scope.seconds == 1 ? 'Second' : 'Seconds';
                    } else {
                    }

                    if (attrs.callback) {
                        $scope.callback();
                    }
                };

                // Countdown here
                if ($scope.isLaunchExact) {
                    $scope.launchUnixSeconds = moment($scope.countdownTo).unix();
                    $interval(countdownProcessor, 1000);
                } else {
                    $scope.countdownText = $scope.countdownTo;
                }
            },
            templateUrl: '/js/templates/countdown.html'
        }
    }]);
})();
```

Here is the Angular controller that is being interfered with:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    //app.value('duScrollDuration', 1000);

    app.controller("homeController", ['$scope', 'Statistic', function($scope, Statistic) {
        $scope.statistics = [];
        $scope.activeStatistic = false;

        $scope.goToClickedStatistic = function(statisticType) {
            history.replaceState('', document.title, '#' + statisticType);
            $scope.activeStatistic = statisticType;
        };

        $scope.goToNeighborStatistic = function(index) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < $scope.statistics.length) {
                var stat = $scope.statistics[index];

                history.replaceState('', document.title, '#' + stat.camelCaseType); // WhyIsThisFlashing
                $scope.activeStatistic = stat.camelCaseType;

                return stat.camelCaseType;
            } else {
                $scope.goHome();
            }
        };

        $scope.goToFirstStatistic = function() {

        };

        $scope.goHome = function() {
            history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
            $scope.activeStatistic = false;
            return 'home';
        };

        /*$window.on('scroll',
            $.debounce(100, function() {
                $('div[data-stat]').fracs('max', 'visible', function(best) {
                    $scope.activeStatistic($(best).data('stat'));
                });
            })
        );*/

        (function() {
            laravel.statistics.forEach(function(statistic) {
                $scope.statistics.push(new Statistic(statistic));
            });

            if (window.location.hash) {
                $scope.activeStatistic = window.location.hash.substring(1);
            }
        })();
    }]);

    app.factory('Statistic', function() {
        return function(statistic) {

            var self = {};

            self.changeSubstatistic = function(newSubstatistic) {
                self.activeSubstatistic = newSubstatistic;
            };

            statistic.forEach(function(substatistic) {

                if (!self.substatistics) {

                    self.substatistics = [];
                    self.activeSubstatistic = substatistic;
                    self.type = substatistic.type;
                    self.camelCaseType = self.type.replace(" ", "");
                }

                self.substatistics.push(substatistic);
            });

            return self;
        }
    });
})();
```

**Each time my countdown directive's `countdownProcessor` function present in the `$interval` is run, `goToNeighborStatistic` in my angular controller is, somehow, called.** I don't have a clue why.

If I step through my countdown directive, after stepping through the `countdownProcessor` function, an "Anonymous Script" named `SCRIPT0` is called with the following contents:

```
"use strict";
var fn=function(s,l,a,i){var v0,v1,v2,v3=l&&('goToNeighborStatistic' in l),v4,v5,v6=l&&('\u0024index' in l);v2=v3?l:s;if(!(v3)){if(s){v1=s.goToNeighborStatistic;}}else{v1=l.goToNeighborStatistic;}if(v1!=null){ensureSafeFunction(v1,text);if(!(v6)){if(s){v5=s.$index;}}else{v5=l.$index;}v4=ifDefined(v5,0)-ifDefined(1,0);ensureSafeObject(v2,text);v0=ensureSafeObject(v2.goToNeighborStatistic(ensureSafeObject(ifDefined(v5,0)-ifDefined(1,0),text)),text);}else{v0=undefined;}return v0;};return fn;
```

Why is "goToNeighborStatistic" present in this? Why is this script even present? From there, `goToNeighborStatistic()` runs, at which point, the countdown is called again and everything repeats. What's going on here?

EDIT:

In Chrome, stepping through everything produces different results. At the end of the `countdownProcessor` function, stepping into produces this:

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear to me because I can't find the text "WhyIsThisFlashing" in your code; where are you setting that? (I realise "WhyIsThisFlashing" is probably debug)

Comment: Sorry, that's just the side effect of the bug. If you look in the `goToNeighborStatistic` function I've annotated the flashing bit. It's changing the hash of the URL normally, I just hardcoded in "WhyIsThisFlashing" for debug purposes as you mentioned.

I digress though, since none of what I really said was relevant to the actual bug, ha.

Comment: I'm guessing you're stepping through in the browser (Chrome?).  If so, does the call stack help at all - I would expect it to show where the call into the code in SCRIPT0 is coming from.  Also, have you cleared your cache in the browser? Does SCRIPT0 look like a minified, older version of the controller file?

Comment: It's called `SCRIPT0` in Firefox. Chrome labels it as `VM305`. The content of the file I've posted already and I did not write it. 

The callstack is not particularly helpful - it just steps through Angular.js.

Comment: I don't see any markup, what do you pass into callback on the directive?

Comment: Post here the piece of html where you use the directive for further discussion.